# How do I get a residence permit in Northern Ireland as a Tunisian citizen with an Irish father?

Tags: united-kingdom, family, tunisian-citizens

My question is how do I get a residence permit in Northern Ireland? I am a resident of my father with Irish citizenship.

I am 26 years old and a Tunisian citizen.

Comment: Your question isn’t very clear. What is your citizenship? Where are you resident now and what permit do you hold (if any)? What research have you done already eg using this tool https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y?

Comment: This seems very much like a question for [Expatriates.SE], but in short the answer is probably that you will not be able to get a residence permit in the United Kingdom based on your relationship with your father unless (1) your father lives in the United Kingdom, and (2) you live with your father there, and (3) you are financially dependent on your father.

Comment: Thank you, I came on a tourist visa, my father is a resident who has a nationality and works.  I am a Tunisian

Comment: If you ask this question on [Expatriates.SE], I'll try to answer it tomorrow.  You can also flag it for migration by clicking the "flag" link above.

Comment: What does “My father has a nationality” mean?

Comment: Were your father or grandparents Irish nationals born in Ireland?  If so, you can claim Irish nationality by descent - which gets you an EU passport *and* the right to reside anywhere in the UK even after Brexit.

Comment: In addition to @MartinBonner's answer, if your father gained Irish Citizen (by naturalization or descent) before you were born (or before 1986), then you can apply for Irish Citizenship by descent via the Foreign Births Register.

Comment: Note that the OP is asking about living in _Northern Ireland_, a part of the UK, and not the Republic of Ireland. Irish citizenship won't help, especially if Brexit comes to pass.